# Relational operator and the precedence of operators

Tags: c, output, operators, addition

I executed a code in the C language, However I am unable to understand its output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=5;
    int b= ++a + 0!=0;
    printf("%d %d",++a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

The output for the above program is

```
7 1
```

I am unable to understand why it is so.

Comment: Lookup [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). The `b` value parses as `((++a) + 0) != 0`..

Comment: When given a problem like this, always ignore the spacing. There is no `0!=0` in that code, but the misleading spacing makes it look like there is. [Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c) is `a --> 0` which is really `a-- > 0`.

Comment: Did you try changing the code a bit to see what happens? changing to `b = 0!=0;` (`b` now `0`) or changing to `b = (++a + 0) != 0;` (`b` now `1`) would reveal what's going on

Answer (score 2):

Order of operations causes this to be treated as:

```
int b = (((++a) + 0) != 0);
```

Therefore:

```
int b = (6 != 0);
```

6 isn't 0, so that has a value of true aka 1.

```
int b = 1;
```